# Electromagnetic field tensor in an orthonormal basis (in SI units)

Tags: orthonormal, exterior-algebra, electromagnetism

Is it true?

Electromagnetic fiel tensor, defined by:

$\mathbf{F}\overset{\text{def}}=B+E\wedge \mathrm{d}t=  B_1\mathrm{d}y\wedge \mathrm{d}z+ B_2\mathrm{d}z\wedge \mathrm{d}x+ B_3\mathrm{d}x\wedge \mathrm{d}y-\frac{E_1}{c}c\mathrm{d}t\wedge \mathrm{d}x
-\frac{E_2}{c}c\mathrm{d}t\wedge \mathrm{d}y
-\frac{E_3}{c}c\mathrm{d}t\wedge \mathrm{d}z$

is (usualy) express using this matrix (first row and second column):

$F_{\mu\nu}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\ 0&E_1/c&E_2/c&E_3/c\\
-E_1/c&0&\color{red}-B_3&\,\,B_2\\
-E_2/c&\,\,B_3&0&\color{red}-B_1\\
-E_3/c& \color{red}-B_2&\,\,B_1&\ 0\end{array}\right)$

in ortonormal basis:
$\Big(\mathrm{d}x\wedge c\mathrm{d}t,\, \mathrm{d}y\wedge c\mathrm{d}t,\,
\mathrm{d}z\wedge c\mathrm{d}t,\, \mathrm{d}y\wedge\mathrm{d}z,\,
\mathrm{d}z\wedge\mathrm{d}x,\,
\mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}y\Big)$,

where $c$ in SI units ensures orthonormality and Minkowski metric tensor is:
$\small\eta=
\begin{pmatrix} c\mathrm{d}t& \mathrm{d}x&
\mathrm{d}y& \mathrm{d}z\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} c\mathrm{d}t\\ \mathrm{d}x\\
\mathrm{d}y\\ \mathrm{d}z\end{pmatrix}$.

Is it posible tensor $F$ express in (orthonormal) basis using matrix multiplication like ordinary vector or covector? How?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes,  $F_{\mu\nu}$ can be expressed in an orthonormal basis using matrix multiplication, just like ordinary vectors or covectors.

Comment: The correct way to relate $\mathbf{F}$ with its components $F_{\mu\nu}$ is the equation $\mathbf{F}=F_{\mu\nu}\,dx^\mu\otimes dx^\nu$ (with summation convention). Since the tensor is anti-symmetric you will find the wedge products when you write that out. In your equation with $\eta$ you mix up a few things. You can't obviously multiply  a $4\times 4$-matrix with those "vectors" that have six componetns.

Comment: Sorry. I had a wrongly expressed metric. I fixed it

Comment: I saw it. Is there any more question left? It shouldn't when you write out the formula I gave.

Comment: Can you writen $\mathbf{F}=\frac{1}{2}F_{\mu\nu}\mathrm{d}x^\mu\wedge \mathrm{d}x^\nu$ like multiplication of matrices? Sorry. I don't see it there. Thanks

Comment: Use the definition $dx^\mu\wedge dx^\nu=dx^\mu\otimes dx^\nu-dx^\nu\otimes dx^\mu\,,$ the anti-symmetry of $F_{\mu\nu}$ and write out both formulas that we now have for $\mathbf{F}\,.$ They should agree.